# Visual Studio 2015: Test Mix Based on User Pace

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I am trying figure out how many times a test will run using the test mix based on user pace. For example, I have a total of 9 test in my load test. One init test and one terminate test. The other 7 test the meat of the load test. Each one has it's on own value defined to the per user per hour pace. Values are as follows:

```
Init-test: log on user
   test-1: 0.15 per user per hour
   test-2: 0.10 per user per hour
   test-3: 0.15 per user per hour
   test-4: 0.30 per user per hour
   test-5: 0.05 per user per hour
   test-6: 0.35 per user per hour
   test-7: 1.10 per user per hour
Terminate-test: Sign off user
```

I am using a "Step" load patter that is defined as follows:

```
Initial User Count: 800
Maximum User Count: 800
Step Duration: 15s
Step Ramp time: 5s
Step User Count: 10s
```

I need to know how to calculate how many times each individual test will be ran. Any help would be most appreciated!!!

Comment: Has your question been answered? If it has then please consider accepting the answer so others know it has been answered. If not then can you [edit] the question to explain what additional information is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers given for the test specification are interesting. By having initial and maximum user counts equal the step pattern is meaningless, it is equivalent to a constant load of, in this case 800. Having a step ramp time of 5 seconds may make it slightly different to a constant load. The load may rise from 0 to 800 in 5 seconds, but after that be constant.

Adding the values for the test pace (test-1: 0.15, 2: 0.10, 3: 0.15, 4: 0.30, 5: 0.05, 6: 0.35, and 7: 1.10 per user per hour) gives a total of 2.2 tests per user hour, excluding the initial and terminate tests. Visual Studio uses random numbers to modify think times and the choice of which test to execute "next", so the 2.2 is approximate.

The total test duration is not given. If the test run duration is one hour and has 800 users then with an an average of 2.2 test cases executed per user per hour the total test executed will be approximately 1760.

This paragraph may not be accurate. The handling of initialisation tests when the test mix is user pace is not clearly defined. However, for user pace I believe that the initialisation tests are additional to those in the test mix. Hence your load pattern should expect 800 executions of the initialisation test, ie one per user. The termination tests are also additional to those in the mix. The number of terminate tests to be executed is determined by the "Percentage of new users" in the properties of the scenario. If the percentage is 0 (zero) then no terminate tests will run. If it is 100% then the terminate test will run after each of the main tests, additionally the initialise test will be run before the next main test. If the value is 50% then you could expect the terminate test to run after half of the main tests, plus another initialise test. As 1760 main tests are expected, a 50% new users would expect 1760/2 == 880 terminates, plus 880 initialises. Hence at 50% expect totals of 800+880 == 1680 initialise tests, 1760 main tests and 880 terminate tests.